# django create user method in model

Tags: python, django, model

Hi I'm new to django and python. I want to extend django `User` model and add a `create_user` method in a model, then I call this `create_user` method from view. However, I got an error msg.

My model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Basic(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

    def create_ck_user(acc_type, fb_id,fb_token):
        # "Create a user and insert into auth_user table"
        user = User.objects.create_user(acc_type,fb_id,fb_token)
        user.save()

class External(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Basic)
    external_id = models.IntegerField()
    locale = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    token = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
```

and in view, I did sth like this:

```
Basic.create_ck_user('acc_type' = 'fb', 'fb_id' = fb_id, 'fb_token' = fb_token)
```

error shows that:

```
keyword can't be an expression (views.py, Basic.objects.create_ck_user('acc_type' = 'fb', 'fb_id' = fb_id, 'fb_token' = fb_token))
```

Edit: 
After add @classmehtod, and change view.py to:

```
...    
if (request.method == 'POST'):
            acc_type = request.POST.get('acc_type')
            fb_id = request.POST.get('fb_id')
            fb_token = request.POST.get('fb_token')

            Basic.create_ck_user(acc_type,fb_id,fb_token)
...
```

An error msg shows:

> create_ck_user() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

checked error details, it includes "request" variable though that i just pass 3 variables: `acc_type`, `fb_id` and `fb_token`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you reference `objects` in there?

Comment: sorry, removed. and try @aychedee's method, but return new error: unbound method create_ck_user() must be called with Basic instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Basic.create_ck_user('fb', fb_id, fb_token)
```

You don't assign to strings when you call a function/method. You assign to variables. But since you are using positional arguments in your function definition then you don't even need them.

Assigning to a string will never work anyway... strings are immutable objects.

Also, you want this method to be a class method. Otherwise you would need to create an instance of User before calling it.

```
# inside class definition  
    @classmethod
    def create_ck_user(cls, acc_type, fb_id,fb_token):
        # "Create a user and insert into auth_user table"
        user = cls.objects.create_user(acc_type,fb_id,fb_token)
        user.save()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but got new error returned: unbound method create_ck_user() must be called with Basic instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to make it a class method. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Making it a classmethod (or indeed any sort of method at all) is pointless, since it doesn't need anything a method would get.

Comment: @aychedee i edited my question 'cause there is a new error said i passed 4 arguments instead of 3. so i change def create_ck_user(acc_type,fb_id,fb_token) to def create_ck_user(request,acc_type,fb_id,fb_token). now it works. but i don't know why. The extra "request" variable looks weird to me.

Comment: Mario, see this line `def create_ck_user(cls, acc_type, fb_id,fb_token):`. See how the `cls` is passed in as the first argument? And then used on the next line? When you make something a classmethod the class is passed in as the first argument. That's why it says four arguments have been passed but you haven't changed the function definition to take four arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just look here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#creating-users

You can find a lot of answers just looking at the documentation.